# Uncaught SyntaxError with "await import(...)"

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-2016

When I try to import a JS module dynamically using the code below, I get `"Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected reserved word"` in both, Firefox and Chrome but [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) it should work.

```
let module = await import('/modules/my-module.js');
```

When I use `.then()` instead of `await`, everything works just fine. Is MDN wrong?

Comment: Top level await is not supported you might need to wrap it in IIFE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write "async" in this function declaration

```
 const my_func = async (arg1,arg2) => {
  let module = await import('/modules/my-module.js');
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this error by trying to use `await` at the top level of a module.

Normally I would expect to see an error along the lines of "Cannot use await outside an async function" but that isn't the case here.

Moving the `await import` inside an async function resolved the problem:

```
<script type="module">
    (async function () {
        let module = await import('/modules/my-module.js');
        console.log(module);
    })();
</script>
```